# Using themes without manifest - App crashes despite theme declared

Tags: android

So my app currently has two themes declared:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeNoBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I want my first screen to have no action bar, and then the rest to use an action bar. I've removed the Theme declaration from AndroidManifest as this was causing the declared theme to overwrite what I declare in my activity xml layouts. In one such case (opening this activity crashes the app):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.DictionaryActivity"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I'm declaring the theme in the XML but it still crashes. The onCreate is as follows:

```
public class DictionaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare theme in your manifest file for application. And if you want you can specify different themes for your activities. Can you try like this:

```
<application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        ...>
        <activity
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar" />
</application>
```

Comment: This was it - I was defining android:theme in the individual activity XML files. Didn't realise it could/needed to be defined in the manifest like this. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> I want my first screen to have no action bar

But in your layout XML file, you use:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" //shoule be AppThemeNoBar
```

And if you want to apply theme using java codes, could do as the following in `onCreate()` method:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setTheme(R.style.MyTheme); // (for Custom theme),must called before setContentView
this.setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
```

Comment: Apologies for the confusion - the given example was not my first screen, which has been set to AppThemeNoBar, but still displays a bar